# J2ME: How to import contact from contact list?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, midp

How do i add the functionality to import a contact number from address book/contact list and add it into an array?

**Edit**

If you have seen the **advanced call manager** app, it allows you to choose a contact from contact list and add to blacklist. I want to do same thing choose a contact from contact list and add to internal array.

**Details:**
Nokia N70
CLDC 1.1
MIDP 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the device supports JSR-75 to get PIM data access. Have a look at this link:  http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75

Comment: @ruibm: I could not find the solution in the link you provided, i have added more info to my question please have a look at it again, hope this clarifies what i mean. thanks

Comment: @Sarfaz: I just had a look at the advanced call manager app. I believe the app is written natively in S60 and it hooks in directly to the phone call API. I believe it's their app that maintains the blacklist not the phone. Finally, I've never used this JSR myself but I would be very surprised if you could have the same degree of flexibility as you do when you use S60 API directly.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications for the PIM API can be downloaded from the link provided by ruibm. Final release -> download page -> PIM Optional Package Specification. I'm not sure what more you could want other than a direct example....

Comment: An actual answer which brings value, maybe?

Comment: @colig: i am not looking for specification here, just how to do it, i know my mobile supports it.

Answer (score 1):

there is 3 options to do so :

1. using symbian c++ instead of j2me 
   http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Nokia_Symbian3_Developers_Library/GUID-B51A9A1F-8E80-4DF6-904A-7BD1A8976BBB.html
2. making your own contact list using PIM api
   http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html
3. adding text field component with this attributes

   TextField num = new TextField("num", "", 20, TextField.PHONENUMBER);

now a command called add from contact is added to this text field and when chosen the default contact list will open and allow you to choose a number that will be written in your text field

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        verifyPIMSupport();
        PIM pimInst = PIM.getInstance();
        contList = (ContactList) pimInst.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);
        enumContacts = contList.items();
        mainList = new List(":.:PHONE BOOK:.:", List.IMPLICIT);
        addCommand = new Command("ADD CONTACTS", Command.OK, 0);
        listCommand = new Command("LIST CONTACTS", Command.OK, 0);
        exitCommand = new Command("EXIT", Command.EXIT, 0);
        deleteCommand = new Command("DELETE ALL", Command.OK, 0);



       while (enumContacts.hasMoreElements()) {

            Contact tCont = (Contact) enumContacts.nextElement();
            String[] name_struct = tCont.getStringArray(Contact.NAME, 0);
            String firstname = name_struct[Contact.NAME_GIVEN];
            String lastname = name_struct[Contact.NAME_FAMILY];
            //String email = tCont.getString(Contact.EMAIL, 0);
           // String number = tCont.getString(Contact.TEL, 0);
            //String org = tCont.getString(Contact.ORG, 0);
            String person = "First Name:" + firstname+ "\n" + "Last Name:"
           + lastname ;
            //String person = "First Name:" + firstname + "\n" + "Last Name:"
           //+ lastname + "\n" + "N0:" + number + "\n" + "Email:" + email + "\n" + "Org:" + org;
            mainList.setFitPolicy(1);
            mainList.append(person, null);
        }
        mainList.addCommand(addCommand);
        mainList.addCommand(listCommand);
        mainList.addCommand(exitCommand);
        mainList.addCommand(deleteCommand);
        mainList.setCommandListener(this);

        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
```

Comment: I think you're either missing some code on this, or the Try shouldn't be in there.  As is it won't compile.